# IPod Touch upgradable?

Tags: ipod-touch

I am interested in picking up an IPod in order to be able to test my apps on both the IPhone and IPod.  I don't really care about the IPod for any other purpose, so I'd be willing to buy a used one.

But the question arises, does an old IPod lack any features or software upgradability that would limit the type of apps I could test on it?  I know nothing about IPods and whether they have evolved their operating system with newer models.

Thanks for any information on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All iPhones and iPod Touches can upgrade the firmware as new versions become available.  Apple has historically charged for updates to iPod Touches.   I can't speak towards older iPods (nanos, classics, etc)

Comment: I did a few updates on my old Nano and there was no charge for that.

Answer (score 4):

Keep in mind that the iPod Touch does not have GPS, Camera, or Microphone.  This can limit your ability in some cases.

Comment: True. Also speakers. Some of the older ones only do headphone audio.

Comment: Actually it does have the GPS and the 3rd gen 32 GB and 64 GB versions have mics (built into the earphones). I'm not sure if there would be a difference in development as far as a built-in mic vs a earphone mic. Some apps seem to get confused with it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Older versions of the ipod touch do not include all the same features as the newer models (camera, etc.), but they do all upgrade. the only problem is that the older versions are not as good with new upgrades as they were originally designed for old software. Hope this helps.

-CodeKid1001